# UserProfile state is null on webchat but ok on directline and emulator

Tags: c#, botframework

I am passing a **StateBotAccessor** around to my multi-dialog bot. I noticed that on **webchat**, retrieving userProfile via _stateBotAccessor.UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync() returns null but conversationData is persisted. Testing via emulator and directline shows a properly filled userProfile.

[I created a git project built from EnterpriseBot template to show the problem.](https://github.com/oyen/EnterpriseBot1)

Here is my simple UserProfile class:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile(string name)
    {
        this.UserName = name;
    }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my simple ConversationData class:

```
public class ConversationData
{
    public ConversationData(string channelId)
    {
        ChannelId = channelId;
    }

    // The ID of the user's channel.
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my StateBotAccessor class:

```
public class StateBotAccessors
{
    public StateBotAccessors(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState)
    {
        ConversationState = conversationState ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("UserProfile");
        UserState = userState ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("ConversationData");
    }

    public IStatePropertyAccessor<UserProfile> UserProfileAccessor { get; set; }

    public IStatePropertyAccessor<ConversationData> ConversationDataAccessor { get; set; }

    public IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> DialogStateAccessor { get; set; }

    public ConversationState ConversationState { get; }

    public UserState UserState { get; }
}
```

On Startup.cs I register StateBotAccessors. I use inMemory storage here and I did test with blob storage but the results are the same.

```
        var dataStore = new MemoryStorage();
        var userState = new UserState(dataStore);
        var conversationState = new ConversationState(dataStore);

        services.AddSingleton(dataStore);

        var stateBotAccessors = new StateBotAccessors(conversationState, userState)
        {
            DialogStateAccessor = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"),
            ConversationDataAccessor = conversationState.CreateProperty<ConversationData>("ConversationData"),
            UserProfileAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>("UserProfile"),
        };
        services.AddSingleton(stateBotAccessors);
```

On my MainDialog.OnStartAsync() I immediately set both userProfile and conversationData:

```
    protected override async Task OnStartAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var context = dc.Context;

        // set userprofile and conversationdata
        await _accessors.ConversationDataAccessor.SetAsync(context, new ConversationData(dc.Context.Activity.ChannelId));
        await _accessors.UserProfileAccessor.SetAsync(context, new UserProfile("Elena"));

        await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"ConversationData and UserProfile were set in MainDialog.OnStartAsync()");

        // easier testing, I have this as a convenience method
        var reply = context.Activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Text = "Say 'print out state' or click the button.";
        reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                {
                    new CardAction(type: ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Test State", value: "print out state"),
                }
        };
        await context.SendActivityAsync(reply);
    }
```

I call SecondDialog if user's text input is "print out state" then I print out the contents of both conversationData and userProfile but userProfile is always NULL on webchat client:

```
        var conversationState = await _accessors.ConversationDataAccessor.GetAsync(sc.Context, () => null);
        var userProfile = await _accessors.UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(sc.Context, () => null);

        await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"conversationState.ChannelId: {conversationState?.ChannelId}");
        await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"userProfile.UserName: {userProfile?.UserName}");
```

The test result looks like this:
[image]

Sample webchat and directline clients are under /Clients folder in the git project.
My webchat client is simple:

```
    const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations', 
        { 
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer mySecretKey",            
            },
        });
    const { token } = await res.json();

    var dl = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token });
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: dl,
      user : user,
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

I want userProfile to persist on webchat channel like it does on emulator and directline channel. Is there something I'm missing? Some special handling for webchat channel perhaps?

Comment: @mjwills I cleaned up the git project and then added a new folder /Clients for a sample directline and webchat client that reflects the issue.

Comment: @mjwills I edited again and put the relevant code in the question text itself. thanks for guiding me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webchat client is very particular with the **userId** - sessions are not persisted unless a specific user id is properly configured.

```
...
var user = {id: 'test@test.com',
            name: 'You'
};
....
var dl = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token });
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: dl,
      userId : user.id,
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```